# Copy files with spaced names from git diff

Tags: git, cp

I want to copy files from local git to another directory like this:

```
git diff --name-only tags/21.4.1 tags/21.4.2| xargs -0 -n 1 -Ifoo cp --parents foo /tmp/archive_build_dir/
cp -pv --parents $(git diff --name-only tags/21.4.1 tags/21.4.2) /tmp/archive_build_dir/
```

But it didn't work for files with spaces in name even if I added double quots to git diff

**UPD:**

Just add delimeter to xargs:

```
  git diff --name-only tags/21.4.1 tags/21.4.2| xargs -0 -n 1 -d "\n" -Ifoo cp --parents foo /tmp/archive_build_dir/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git diff` has a [`-z` option](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#Documentation/git-diff.txt--z) :

> -z
>
> When --raw, --numstat, --name-only or --name-status has been given, do not munge pathnames and use NULs as output field terminators.
>
> Without this option, pathnames with "unusual" characters are quoted as explained for the configuration variable core.quotePath (see git-config[1]).

You should use this option if you want to combine its output with `xargs -0 ...`